# Insert values in specific position of array javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

First I am creating an array with an specific size.

```
$("#bntSize").one('click', function(e){
          var memoria = $("#memoria").val();
          console.log(memoria)

          html = "";

          for(var i = 0; i < memoria ; i++){
               html += "<div class='square' name='mem"+i+"' data-id='"+i+"' data-pos='"+i+"' >"+i+"</div>";
               arrayMemoria.push('');
          }
          console.log(arrayMemoria)
          $("#contenedor").html(html);

        });
```

If memoria is equal to 7 I am getting this:

```
["", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Now I am giving some values to the array:

```
var nada = 0;

function firstFit(){

          var cantidad = $("#ffinput").val();
          var value = $("#ffinput2").val();
          /*console.log(cantidad)*/

         if(nada == 0){
            for (nada ; nada < cantidad ; nada++) {
                arrayMemoria.splice(nada , 1 , value);
                nada = nada;
            }
         }
         else{

            for (nada; nada < arrayMemoria.length ; nada++) {
                arrayMemoria.splice(nada , 1 , value);
                nada = nada;
            }
         }
```

Here **cantidad:** how many spaces I am suppose to use in array & **value:** just a value.

So if I put => cantidad = 3 and value = A

```
["A", "A", "A", "", "", "", ""]
```

Then if I want to put => cantidad = 2 and value = B

```
["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"]
```

But I am trying to get this:

```
["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "", ""]
```

and if I put => cantidad = 1 and value = C

```
["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", ""]
```

**And my second problem**

If I do remove the values equals to A and I am inserting => cantidad = 2 AND VALUE = D 
I am suppose to get this:

```
["D", "D", "", "B", "B", "C", ""]
```

How to count the available space in my array? cause if I want to insert

cantidad = 1 and value = E , I need to get the first available space

```
["D", "D", "E", "B", "B", "C", ""]
```

If someone can help me please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code

```js
 var arr = ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    arr = insertValue(3, "A", arr);
    console.log(arr);
    arr = insertValue(2, "B", arr);
    console.log(arr);
    arr = insertValue(1, "C", arr);
    console.log(arr)
    arr = removeValue("A", arr);
    console.log(arr)
    arr = insertValue(2, "D", arr);
    console.log(arr)
    
    
 function insertValue(cantidad, value, arr){
  var arrLength = arr.length;
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
   if(arr[i] == "" && count < cantidad){
    arr[i] = value;
    count ++;
   }
  };
      return arr;
 }

 function removeValue(value, arr){
  var arrLength = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
   if(arr[i] == value){
    arr[i] = "";
   }
  };
      return arr;
 }
```

**EDIT:** To get the number of spaces in the array

```js
var arr = ["A", "A", " " , " ", " " , "B" ,"C " , " "];
var  spaceCount = 0; 

arr.forEach(function(i) { if(i == " ") spaceCount++;  });
console.log(spaceCount)
```

**EDIT 2:** To count consecutive spaces in an array

```js
var arr = ["A", "A", " " , " ", " " , "B"," ", " " ,"C " , " "];
var count = 1;
var countArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 if(arr[i] == " "){
  if(arr[i+1] == arr[i]){
   count ++;
  }else {
   countArr.push(count);
   count = 1;
  }
 }
};

console.log(countArr)
```

**EDIT 3:** To get consecutive space count + starting position

```js
var arr = [" ", "A", "A", " " , " ", " " , "B"," ", " " ,"C " , " "];
var count = 1;
var countArr = [];

var pos = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 if(arr[i] == " "){
  if(arr[i] === arr[i+1]){
   count ++;
  }else {
   countArr.push({'pos': pos, 'count': count});
   count = 1;
  }
 }else{
  pos = i+1;
 }
};

console.log(countArr)
```

Comment: can you help me with one more problem? what happen if i have this array `["A", "A", " " , " ", "B",  " " , " " , " "]` and i want to insert cantidad = 1 , and the expected result will be `["A", "A", " " , " ",  " " , "B" ,"C " , " "]` and if i want to insert cantidad = 3   `["A", "A", "D" , "D ", "D", "B",  " C", " "]` , how i can count exactly how many blank space are in the array and put the value in the best position to save space for a bigger cantidad

Comment: Any way to count consecutive spaces? i mean : count the first 3 spaces: `count = 3 ` and then `count = 1` for the last space, so in that way i will know that i have to insert the value in the last space.

Comment: @Eliott I have added the code for consecutive spaces in an array

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var array = ["A", "", "", "", "B", "B", "B"];

  var cantidad = 2;
  for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    if (array[x] === "") {
      if (cantidad >0){
        array.splice(x, 1, "C");
        cantidad--;
      }
    }
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    alert(array);
  }

  window.onload = codeAddress;
```

Here's a solution, I realized you can solve this problem in a lot of different ways, mine is not necessarily the best approach.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is a working solution for both questions.

```js
var array = ["","","","","","",""];

function addValues(num, value) {
    for(var i=0; i<num; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<array.length; j++){
            if(array[j] ==="") {
                array[j] = value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function removeValues(value) {
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if(array.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            array[i] = "";
        }
    }

}
addValues(3, 'A');
addValues(2, 'B');
addValues(1, 'C');

removeValues('A');

addValues(2, 'D');
addValues(2, 'E');

console.log(array);
```